# Use VerbNet, NLTK to parse verbs

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to identify the verbs used in sentences and determine whether the verb is being used with a literal or figurative meaning. I think I should use VerbNet and NLTK. But, I have never used VerbNet. How do I start?

Comment: See this tutorial: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/lope.linguistics.ntu.edu.tw/courses/python4nlp/week6-2.Working.with.Lexical.Data.2.ipynb

Comment: also http://n0b3l1a.blogspot.de/2009/10/wordnet-verbnet-via-python-nltk.html

Answer (score 5):

Well I am not sure regarding the first part of the question. Perhaps [word sense disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_disambiguation) might help you here. Regarding the second part you must first download the verbnet corpus,use this :`>>>import nltk >>>nltk.download()`. Then you can refer to [this link](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#verbnet-corpus-reader) for a primer on the methods. The basic structure and organisation of verbnet can be read [here](http://verbs.colorado.edu/~kipper/Papers/dissertation.pdf) and [here](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/VerbNet_Guidelines.pdf)

The verb net is basically divided into 'verb classes' which contain the verbs which have similar syntactic and semantic properties. So a given verb say 'accept' can be used in many ways.All those variations are captured by the following Verb net classes : 'approve-77', 'characterize-29.2-1-1', 'obtain-13.5.2'.The full index of verb net classes can be found [here](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/vn/class-h.php).

For more info refer to [this link](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html) and go to the subsection 'verbnet' in section 1.12. Also the Verbnet is also integrated with Wordnet. The means you can access a Verb net 'class' corresponding to the Wordnet 'word sense '. Please refer to the earlier links for more information.

Hope this helps